# How to combine a list of lists into string in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, counter

I have a list which contain multiple lists, i want to combine these lists into single string so that i can use counter() method on it.

Sample List

```
 List1= [
     ['this is the first document',
     'this document is the second document'],
     ['and this is the third one',
     'is this the first document']]
```

Output required 
'this is the first document this document is the second document and this is the third one is this the first document'

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the .join() method:

```
list1= ['this is the first document', 'this document is the second document', 'and this is the third one', 'is this the first document']

list1_joined = ",".join(list1)
print(list1_joined)

#Output:
'this is the first document,this document is the second document,and this is the third one,is this the first document'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in `join()` function:

```
list = [ 'this is the first document', 'this document is the second document', 'and this is the third one', 'is this the first document']
print(', '.join(list))
```

Output:

```
this is the first document, this document is the second document, and this is the third one, is this the first document
```

Answer (score 0):

create a counter object and iterate through it using object_name.element() and print.

```
  c = Counter(List1) 
  for i in c.elements(): 
       print ( i, end = " ")
```

for more info [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-counter-objects-elements/][1]

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the entire list of lists and append to a string.

Something along the lines of

```
l = [['...','..'],['..']...]
result = ''
for sublist in l:
  for item in sublist:
    result += item
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
outer_list = [["innerlist1element1", "innerlist1element2"],["innerlist2element1","innerlist2element2"]]
res_string = ""
for innerlist in outer_list:
    res_string+= ' '.join(innerlist)+" "
print(res_string)
```

for loop iterates through lists inside the outer list, and join() joins all of its elements with a whitespace in between. However, to join the resultant strings, good old concatenation '+' is used.

**Replacing for loop with list comprehension:**

```py
outer_list = [["innerlist1element1", "innerlist1element2"],["innerlist2element1","innerlist2element2"]]
a = [' '.join(i) for i in outer_list]
print(' '.join(a))
```

List comprehensions are faster and more readable.
See it in [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for more.

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.